# Cubic line graph not graphing correctly?

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js

I have a cubic line graph here: https://jsfiddle.net/v6bLu80w/2/ , which is supposed to graph a line to go through the three points shown, at all times. The slider above it augments the equation, while keeping it within the dots. Or at least, it should, which brings me to my question.

In my graph, I use the following equations to set the coefficients of the cubic:

```
xzero = (thirdy - (firsty * Math.pow(thirdx, 3) / Math.pow(firstx, 3)) + (secondy * Math.pow(thirdx, 3) / firstx) - (Math.pow(thirdx, 3) * (firsty * Math.pow(secondx, 3) / Math.pow(firstx, 3)) / firstx) + (Math.pow(thirdx, 3) * (xone * (secondx, 3) / Math.pow(xone, 2)) / firstx) + (xone * Math.pow(thirdx, 3) / Math.pow(firstx, 2)) - secondy * Math.pow(thirdx, 2) + (firsty * Math.pow(secondx, 3) * Math.pow(thirdx, 2) / Math.pow(firstx, 3)) - (xone * Math.pow(secondx, 3) * Math.pow(thirdx, 2) / Math.pow(firstx, 2)) + (xone * secondx * Math.pow(thirdx, 2)) - xone * thirdx) / (1 + (Math.pow(secondx, 3) * Math.pow(thirdx, 2) / Math.pow(firstx, 3)) + (Math.pow(thirdx, 3) / firstx) - Math.pow(thirdx, 2) - (Math.pow(secondx, 3) * Math.pow(thirdx, 3) * (1 / Math.pow(firstx, 3)) / firstx))

xtwo = (secondy - (firsty * Math.pow(secondx, 3) / Math.pow(firstx, 3)) + (xone * Math.pow(secondx, 3) / Math.pow(firstx, 2)) + (xzero * Math.pow(secondx, 3) / Math.pow(firstx, 3)) - xone * secondx - xzero) / (Math.pow(secondx, 2) - (Math.pow(secondx, 3) / firstx));
xthree = (firsty / Math.pow(firstx, 3)) - (xtwo / firstx) - (xone / Math.pow(firstx, 2)) - (xzero / Math.pow(firstx, 3));
```

According to the algebra that I used, all of the equations should be going through the three dots, but as can be seen in the program, the line will move out of the third dots for all slider values except the starting value.

I want to know why it isn't going through the third point, and any fixes for this situation, if possible, please.

I still can't figure out the problem, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have this statement (split over lines):

```
xzero = (
    thirdy 
    - (firsty * Math.pow(thirdx, 3) / Math.pow(firstx, 3)) 
    + (secondy * Math.pow(thirdx, 3) / firstx) 
    - (Math.pow(thirdx, 3) * (firsty * Math.pow(secondx, 3) / Math.pow(firstx, 3)) / firstx) 
    + (Math.pow(thirdx, 3) * (xone * (secondx, 3) / Math.pow(xone, 2)) / firstx) 
    + (xone * Math.pow(thirdx, 3) / Math.pow(firstx, 2)) 
    - secondy * Math.pow(thirdx, 2) 
    + (firsty * Math.pow(secondx, 3) * Math.pow(thirdx, 2) / Math.pow(firstx, 3)) 
    - (xone * Math.pow(secondx, 3) * Math.pow(thirdx, 2) / Math.pow(firstx, 2)) 
    + (xone * secondx * Math.pow(thirdx, 2)) 
    - xone * thirdx
) / (
    1 
    + (Math.pow(secondx, 3) * Math.pow(thirdx, 2) / Math.pow(firstx, 3)) 
    + (Math.pow(thirdx, 3) / firstx) 
    - Math.pow(thirdx, 2) 
    - (Math.pow(secondx, 3) * Math.pow(thirdx, 3) * (1 / Math.pow(firstx, 3)) / firstx )
)
```

There are a few problems here. By far the biggest one is that this is a hugely long statement which puts far too much in one place and is very easy to make mistakes in constructing, because humans are in fact very bad at keeping track of brackets. At the very least **get an editor with bracket highlighting** so that you are alerted as to which bracket you are closing at the earliest opportunity.

Statements like this go wrong for several reasons:

1. You lose track of the brackets. On the first attempt at formatting, I thought there was an extra closing bracket at the end. Which term was that supposed to close? Was there in fact a missing open-bracket? Have I got the brackets wrong in the formatting?
2. Because it is not split into smaller pieces, it is hard to pick out an intermediate value and see if it fits your expectations, i.e. a test example. It all works or none of it, hence your current problem.
3. It is impossible to read. This is write-only code, which takes careful study to begin to understand. It took a couple of minutes merely to format the lines. The sheer mass of it with all the brackets defies the capacity of your brain to spot mistakes on any level, for example the bit where you have `xone * (secondx, 3)` which seems to result in `xone * 3` in a console for me, but seems unlikely to be correct.

I suspect the reason it still seems to work for the first 2 points is that having calculated the xzero coefficient, you then use the coordinates of the first two points (but not the third) to get the other coefficients. This constructs a curve through those two points and another point based on your xzero formulation, hence the behaviour you see.

In general, it is hard to translate mathematical formulae into code in a sensible way. Not impossible, but worth making an effort for. Often, adding comments in pseudo-math above the calculation of each coefficient or factor makes it easier to write correct code in the first place, let alone to fix mistakes later.

If you had a function to solve for a specific set of values and return an answer (rather than directly updating global variables), then you could write a unit test for a specific case by calling the function and checking the return values. Doing so for some very basic cases (y = constant, y = x, y = -x^2) would rapidly indicate the source of the error because the values of the coefficients would be obviously right or wrong. Code like this needs building up from the simple to the complex. I used to think I was clever if I could dive in at the top and get a load of numerical code right. Now I realise my foolishness.

Regarding the solve being performed in the statement above; since you are solving for the 3 coefficients (`xone` is given) and given 3 x,y pairs, it is entirely possible to do a rank-3 matrix inversion to get the coefficients. For that, there are code samples, libraries and so on available. Reformulating this as a matrix inversion also unlocks the maths surrounding such inversions, in particular the combinations of inputs for which the answer is not knowable - for example where your denominator term would be zero, or where firstx is zero and your numerator and denominator would both be infinite... In other words, leverage the considerable work done already to make your solution really properly good.

Comment: Thanks Phil. Actually, by rewriting the formula so that it would use variables more, I had already corrected the error, which turned out to be a careless mistake. I thought for sure that I had answered and closed it though, but your explanation is a lot better than I could have done.